# regex strip domain name

Tags: javascript, regex

A quick simple regex question

I have a domain name in a string that I need to strip - There is always `http://www.` and the domain always ends in "`/`"

```
g_adv_fullpath_old = g_adv_fullpath_old.replace(/http\:\/\/www\.(.*?)\//ig, '');
```

how do I create the regex to strip the domain name?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you want to replace the domain name with an empty string?

Comment: the ':' doesn't need to be escaped by the way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would simply split on "/".  For example:

```
>>> "http://www.asdf.com/a/b/c".split("/").slice(3).join("/")
'a/b/c'
```

Answer (score 2):

Why complications? Simple `indexOf` will do.
First remove `http://www` (10 characters), then everything before the first slash.

```
var s = "http://www.google.com/test";
s = s.substr(10);
s = s.substr(s.indexOf('/'));
alert(s);
```

Or `split`, as **David** suggests.

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/TqKJT/)

Comment: Do you mean `s.substr(s.substr(10).indexOf("/") + 10)`? That exact code will alert `"le.com/test"`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to remove the `http://www.` and the following slash (plus anything after it) Try:

```
g_adv_fullpath_old.replace(/http:\/\/www\.(.*?)\/.*/ig, '$1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend the stringobject so it supports urlParts

**Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/stofke/Uwdha/

**Javascript**

```
String.prototype.urlParts = function() {
    var loc = this;
    loc = loc.split(/([a-z0-9_\-]{1,5}:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9_\-]{1,}):([a-z0-9_\-]{1,})\@)?((www\.)|([a-z0-9_\-]{1,}\.)+)?([a-z0-9_\-]{3,})((\.[a-z]{2,4})(:(\d{1,5}))?)(\/([a-z0-9_\-]{1,}\/)+)?([a-z0-9_\-]{1,})?(\.[a-z]{2,})?(\?)?(((\&)?[a-z0-9_\-]{1,}(\=[a-z0-9_\-]{1,})?)+)?/g);
    loc.href = this;
    loc.protocol = loc[1];
    loc.user = loc[3];
    loc.password = loc[4];
    loc.subdomain = loc[5];
    loc.domain = loc[8];
    loc.domainextension = loc[10];
    loc.port = loc[12];
    loc.path = loc[13];
    loc.file = loc[15];
    loc.filetype = loc[16];
    loc.query = loc[18];
    loc.anchor = loc[22];
    //return the final object
    return loc;
};
```

**Usage:**

```
 var link = "http://myusername:mypassword@test.asdf.com/a/b/c/index.php?test1=5&test2=789#tite";
 var path = link.urlParts().path;
 var path = link.urlParts().user;
```